# Does this fall into a typical optimization problem? (Knapsack??)

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming

**MOVED TO OR STACK**

I am struggling to find a representative problem formulation for this optimization challenge. I have implemented a MILP in Matlab, but the run time is taking more then a day. My goal is to see if it fits the methods of some other common problems, where I may be able to apply some well known heuristics.

Given a set , $S$, of $n$ discrete items, $i$,  and $k$ subsets, $M$, of $S$ 
$$ S :=\{i_1,i_2,i_3\dots,i_n\} $$
$$ M_{1,2,3,\dots k} \subseteq S $$

Choose exactly $X$ subsets $M$, such that $$X < k$$ to minimize the number of items $i$ that are in 2 or more of the $X$ subsets.

**ADDT'L Notes**

1. There is no extra value if the items $i$ are selected 0 or 1 times, just less then 2
2. Every item $i$ **IS NOT** required to be selected
3. Each subset is predefined, and pseudo random

$$ ---- Below is just a different attempt at formulation---- $$

I tried to keep it more math definition oriented above,  but the other way I simplified the problem is (using my some programming aspects):

1) I have a logical matrix , M ( i rows, j col) , where the rows represent the population and the columns represent the available subsets. 
2) Goal is to optimize F, a column vector ( j , 1), that represents the choice of each subset (columns of M) to minimize the number of elements of M x F that are >= 2;
3) F is subject to you are required to choose exactly X subsets.

Need to define a column logical vector F (j rows, 1 columns) such that F has K true entries (representing the sub set choices) and the rest are false

i = 1e6;
j = 150;
X = 140

Set_Matrix = randi( [0 1], i , j );

Optimize F as to 
Minimize : sum(sum(Set_Matrix * F) >= 2)
Where  sum(F) == X (I.e pick 140 of the 150 subsets)

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, try (with linking of posts or delete here) at https://or.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thank you @MarkL.Stone, i was unaware of OR stack.